# in MySQL what is the most efficient way to count impressions

Tags: php, mysql

I'm going to be displaying an array of rows per page and every time a row shows up on the page i want it to add 1 "hit" to its row impression count. but it seems like there might be a better way than to upon echo do a whole mysql_query function for each listing. is there a way to upon retrieval add 1 to all rows in the query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get all the unique id's from your initial select command, then from PHP store them in a comma separated string and use the IN function of mysql.  Something like:

```
   UPDATE your_table SET impression_count = impression_count + 1 WHERE unique_id IN (yourlistofIDs)
```

That will update all the rows with just 1 query.

Comment: that's what i was thinking too. So there isn't a way to update via the same select query?

Answer (score 1):

we use a mix of db + cache. This allow us to display the data really fast and keep it persistent. We insert a record on a table that has each unique view for all items and after that we increment a counter for that specific row in memcache.

A background process (this could be [sharded or not](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shard_%28database_architecture%29)) processes those row each minute and increments the view in the row at the same time that updates the cache with the *new* total in case there is *offset* between the persistent data and memcache.

*what do we get here?*

- Speed: insert and forget in the *views* table. Increment the cache to show views quickly
- Persistence: when the background process runs, it grabs the data from the db and updates the *db* *AND* the *cache* so your data looks always coherent.